# Making a hollow, 3-D pipe/duct: after joining two cubes, how can I delete the surface inside the pipe/duct to make it hollow?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry

[image]

What is the simplest possible method for making a 3-D hollow pipe/duct out of two cubes in Blender?  One example of what I'd like to achieve is shown above (I would like to do this many times and change the dimensions of the joined bodies).  This question has been asked before.  I have spent the last couple of days googling and trying to understand explanations, but either I get lost or nothing has worked for me.  It seems like many of the available explanations are designed for 2-D and I can't extend them to my setup.

More detail:
I have to use two cubes of different size to make a pipe/duct.  I will have to do this many, many times, so would prefer to find a fast method.  I can't eyeball/estimate anything about the fit or size or orientation of the cubes because I'm trying to make a geometry for use in a simulation.  My problem is that when I join the cubes, I have a surface crossing the pipe/duct at the join (in the figure below, this surface is oriented the same way as the grid).  I have tried using the "knife project" tool, but I don't have vertices in the right place to use it and can't figure out how to get them.  In one online resource, someone mentioned a "Union" addon, but it doesn't appear in my list of add-ons.

Is there a simple way to do this?  All I need to do is get rid of one surface of each cube and then join the cubes.

Comment: Is it possible to show some screenshots of what exactly you are trying to achieve? So far I think the answer to your question might be here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28190/a-problem-with-blenders-bridge-edge-loops-system

Comment: Thank you Mr Zak. I'll upload a couple of shots right now and will check out your link.

Comment: I found in an earlier question that objects of your size are generally harder to work with, i would start by making it not the size of sears tower.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Vince.  Unfortunately, I don't have much of a choice about my dimensions!  I could, of course, do some initial tests at smaller scales though.

Comment: Answer coming up, gimme a sec here.

Comment: Thanks so much, Vince. I have to step out for about an hour, but will be back.

Comment: Perfectly alright, takes me a while to write an answer anyhow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't know if I quite understood the question correctly, but  what I got out of it tells me you have a shape like this:

[image]

And that you want to make sure that the intersection there is clean, and not screwy.

This can be accomplished with Loop-Cut-an-Slide tool. It can be accessed in edit mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. when you place it on the upper cube, it looks like this:

[image]

Don't bother sliding it, just click and place it there for now. Next you're gonna want to turn on vertex snapping, it can be found on the bottom bar of your 3D view-port. Click the magnet to turn on snapping, then click the grid icon just right of it and change it to vertex, portrayed by a grey cube with two white studs on it [image]

once this is enabled you can select the four vertices of the loop you added and hit <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to **G**rab them down on the **Z** axis.

now, if you mouse over one of the vertices of your bottom cube until an orange circle appears around it, then click to finish placement.

[image]

Now all you have to do is remove those inner four vertices to get a clean cut.

If you add two loop-cuts on the bottom cube and hit<kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
 to **S**cale them on the **X** axis and then snap them to the new bottom of your top cube. Now remove doubles and your gold!

[image]

You can also do this by simply grabbing the four vertices that you don't like and <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to **G**rab them up on the **Z** axis until they snap with the top of the top cube.

Sorry for the super long answer. :D hope this helps, Ciao!

Comment: Wow, thank you for going to so much trouble, Vince!  I am trying it out right now.  It may take me a while but it looks promising.

Comment: Vince, sorry if I don't understand correctly.  I need to be able to flow fluid through the geometry.  So I want to remove the surface where the cubes join.  Your answer helps me with another issue, so thanks for that.  It might also help me solve my problem...  I will work with it.

Comment: You can! just delete the entire top face and ramake the ones on either side by selecting the four corners and hitting  [F].

Comment: I'll try it!  It will probably take me a while because I'm not very fast in Blender yet.  Thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: Vince, it worked!!  Thank you so much!  I have spent nearly a week on this and was ready to give up on Blender. Unfortunately, I can't vote you up because I'm not important enough.

Comment: It's alright. just glad to help.! have fun with your project!