# Will Warp bridge these two objects?

Tags: modifiers, objects

I've read documentation and StackExchange for two days or more and installed 2.74, but I'm still lost.  I watched one Warp tutorial which appeared to do what I wanted, which is to create a bridge between the two objects, but I couldn't duplicate the result.  I got some modification between the end points, but no fill.
The objects which I'm working with present matching planes, but if one were scaled, that would be my next question.  Also, the "curve" option of warp seems to be what I need, but there should also be some rotation to get a smooth transition between the two objects.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x44ua54ac1pvfnm/warp.blend?dl=0

Thanks for any help.

The 90 degree question and bending pipe didn't answer my question.  @cegaton suggested the following as a possible solution.  This may be the answer, but it may also be beyond my life expectancy to implement.

[A problem with Blender's Bridge Edge Loops system](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28190/a-problem-with-blenders-bridge-edge-loops-system)

What a comprehensive user friendly program.

The succinct statement of my problem may be: join two faces whose normals don't with a projection of a user shape.
Can curve, bend or warp do that?  I haven't been able to do that, and, from Allen's post, doubt that they can.

Comment: Do you want to connect those 2 parts together? Your question is not very clear

Comment: Yes, I want to connect the two parts together.  Isn't that descriptive of bridge?

Comment: Warp was a bit confusing. You can use bridge edgeloops but you will need even amount of edges.

Comment: Where do you find this stuff?  Seriously, is it documented, or something you know by studying the Python code, or reading every StackExchange post?  I use Blender for revisions of STL files, but have not needed to know much about generating shapes and structures beyond the primitives.  If you can provide details, it would be appreciated.

Comment: blender manual: https://www.blender.org/manual/

Comment: Check this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-90%C2%B0-joint

Comment: That looks like it should work.  The devil is in my following all of the nuances, whether it's a tutorial or the manual.  Thanks.

Comment: By the way, there is a warp tool, but it doesn't do what it sounds like you want to do. Are you looking for the bridge tool?

Comment: related?: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28190/a-problem-with-blenders-bridge-edge-loops-system

Comment: I've worn out bridge, curve and warp since I posted this. I believe **@cegaton comment contains all of the elements of my question**.  Now I can spend a few days figuring out add-ons and perhaps even Python ... to find out if this will .solve my problem.

Comment: See [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1688/599) for installing addons. [bridge](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html?#bridge-edge-loops) *sounds* like exactly what you want.. Is it possible you could upload some screenshots or a .blend showing what your setup is and what happens when you try and use bridge?

Comment: This comment from cegaton's reference above:"If two surfaces in Blender are not on the same plane, the mesh folds on itself. No amount of cuts or twisting or even angling the faces toward each other (as some tutorials say) save the day. Additionally, I have very little option in the way of tweaking the bridge's shape afterward."  Just another feature?  I'm going to work on the info contained in Q28190 today...

Comment: I think the TubeTool is the way to go for this question, not warp..not spin..not bridge..

Answer (score 1):

In blender there are two Warps.

#### Warp Tool

The Warp tool pulls selected vertices towards the 3d-cursor. thats *it*.

#### Warp Modifier

The Warp modifier, doesn't appear to do what you'd like it to. It will warp in a straight line from A to B.

---

#### Tube Tool (can ..sortof)

TubeTool comes closer. Here a a description ( https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28193/47 ) and here the link to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/zeffii/TubeTool). Feedback welcome.

[image]

TubeTool labours under the assumption (currently) that the selected faces are part of one object. At present that means maybe duplicating them, separating selection and then joining them together into one object. The faint blue line emanating from the faces shows their normal, tube tool allows you to flip the perceived normal by providing an option to specify direction (negative or positive).

This will at the very least give you a nice curve between the two faces, from that point you can select a *Bevel Object* or reduce the amount of subdivisions in the default bevel circle. The upside to attaching a *Bevel Object* once the curve is created is that you can adjust the geometry of the *Bevel Object* to match the two faces.

TubeTool isn't very sophisticated yet, but it could be worth checking anyway - and I'm open to suggestions.